# How can a variable be declared from passed loop parameter?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

Instead of doing this manually:

```
let test1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('test1'));
let test2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('test2'));
let test3 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('test3'));
window.onresize = () => {
  test1.resize({
    height: 400,
    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
  });
  test2.resize({
    height: 400,
    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
  });
  test3.resize({
    height: 400,
    width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
  });
};
```

I'd like to iterate through the array but `value` get an error, can't redeclare variable

```
const report = [
    'test1',
    'test2',
    'test3',
];

report.forEach((value) => {
    value = echarts.init(document.getElementById(value));
    window.onresize = () => {
        value.resize({
        height: 400,
        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider restructuring using `Array.prototype.map()` to build an array of reports from an array of ids. Then create a single resize listener which iterates through those reports to perform a resize.

```
const reportIds = [
  'test1',
  'test2',
  'test3',
];

// create an array of reports from an array of ids
const reports = reportIds.map(id => echarts.init(document.getElementById(id)));

// add a single resize listener which handles all reports
window.addEventListener("resize", e => {
  reports.forEach(report => {
    report.resize({
      height: 400,
      width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this one works, thanks!

Comment: I get an error on esLint: `iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations  no-restricted-syntax`

Comment: never mind. I fixed it. I replaced the for loop with foreach.

Answer (score -2):

I think I'd use an object instead:

```js
const report = {
    'test1': "",
    'test2': "",
    'test3': ""
};

Object.keys(report).forEach((value) => {
  
    report[value] = echarts.init(document.getElementById(value));
    window.onresize = () => {
        report[value].resize({
        height: 400,
        width: document.documentElement.clientWidth - 60,
        });
    };
    */
});
```

Comment: This one breaks the eCharts init.

Comment: How does it break it? What's the error message? That wasn't included, so I can't debug that part.

Comment: It just says: Uncaught TypeError: t is null

Comment: There's no variable `t` here. Which line is it referring to?

Comment: you are calling echarts. So report[value].resize is not working.

Comment: How is that different than your original `test1.resize(...)`?